# How to analyze Journey with group of Contacts?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a Journey that from time to time will receive some Contacts. One day will receive 2,000 contacts, two weeks after can receive other 2,000 contacts (the time and number of contacts can vary).

The Journey has a duration of a month and a half. I need to analyze, make report and check the success (opening, bounced back...) in each group of contacts inserted and not all the journey and all contacts in it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use data views to get the [click](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5), [open](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_open.htm&type=5), [bounce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_bounce.htm&type=5),.. data based on EventDate and TriggeredSendCustomerKey fields.

Example: get subscribers who opened the email with TriggeredSendCustomerKey= 'XXXXX' on '2019-10-10'

```
SELECT 
  s.SubscriberKey,
  s.EventDate AS Sent_Date
FROM _Sent s
INNER JOIN _Open o ON s.SubscriberKey = o.SubscriberKey
WHERE 
CAST(o.EventDate AS DATE) = CAST('2019-10-10' AS DATE) 
AND s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey = 'XXXXX'
```

You can use the [JourneyActivity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_journey_activity.htm&type=5) and [Journey](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_journey.htm&type=5) data views to get data related to a specific journey instead of a specific email.

Comment: I agree.  It's better to key off of the `TriggeredSendCustomerKey` in the `_Sent` data view since the JobIds change every time you make a new version or change any journey email definitions. The TriggeredSend Definitions are republished in both cases, which means new JobIds.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer accordingly